# 'File/File.h' (Parse/Parse.h) not found on Archive / Profile with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5, parse-platform

I'm using an external framework (Parse) in my project. Everything runs smoothly when running, testing and analyzing, but archiving and profiling both throw:

> Lexical or Preprocesor Issue: 'Parse.Parse.h' file not found

I've remedied issues with other static library/framework .headers not being found during archive in the past by altering the Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths, but that plan of attack just isn't working here. Namely, I've included

> $(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include"
>
> $(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/../UninstalledProducts/include"
>
> $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)

in the Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths for Build + Release with no result. (I know that's redundant, especially since I've set Always Search User Paths to YES, but I'm trying everything here.) I've tried adding the .h file directly to Copy Bundle Resources in a last ditch effort. Also tried removing and re-adding the framework, cleaning, etc but I've had no luck. Any thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify you have

> ## import "Parse/Parse.h"

in your header file.

Try to do a product->Analyze.

Make sure you have added parse.framework and it has all these header files:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. While we had followed the steps you suggested above, it turned out we were having issues with relative paths across different workspaces on the team. For anyone having similar issues, we turned to Cocoapods and everything is working great now. If Cocoapods aren't a viable option for you, double/triple check that your relative search paths are correct across workspaces if you're working on a team!

Comment: I've worked independently the entire time, so I'm not familiar with nor do I currently have a need for Cocoapods, but it's good to know.